# How to use CompareTo() Lexicographically?

Tags: java, class, compareto

Good morning/night, I am a beginner in java. I'm making a class for a program where people can set locations with various variables (state, country, latitude, etc) as a way to practice using multiple classes for a project. In this class (called `Location`), I'm forced to use `compareTo()` in a way I haven't used it before since I'm implementing the `Comparable` class. I know `compareTo()` is used to compare strings by seeing if they're the same or different, but this time I'm comparing two objects within a method. How would I sort these objects within the method and still return an int?

This is my `Location` class at the moment. I would have only posted the current method, but based on other posts in the forum, it's good to show the a good chunk of the class.

```
public class Location implements Comparable<Location> {

    //Done for now
    private String state;
    private String county;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private int elevation;
   
    public Location(String state, String county) throws IllegalArgumentException {
       this.state = state;
       this.county = county;
    }
    //...
    //various getters and setters for mentioned variables...
    //...

    public int compareTo(Location a){ //must compare objs and return an int
       int result = this.compareTo(a);
 
       if (result == 0){
        // the equal
            return result;
        } else if (result < 0){
            //not equal, one would be higher than the other
            return result;
        } else{
            //Same as comment above
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I have been looking in forums and some java focused websites for help, but they only show it in the way I'm used to using the method (think s1.comparesTo(s2)). I haven't stumbled upon any posts that involves implementing `Comparable`.

Comment: You (or your assignment) must first decide what it means for one Location to be ordered before another.  Are they ordered by latitude/longitude?  Are they ordered alphabetically by county then state?  The answer will determine what code you need to write in your `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 2):

Why not cheat and use the `Comparator` builder?

```
public class Location implements Comparable<Location> {
    private static final Comparator<Location> comparator = Comparator.comparing((Location l) -> l.state)
        .thenComparing(l -> l.county)
        .thenComparingDouble(l -> l.latitude)
        ...;

    public int compareTo(Location a) {
        return comparator.compare(this, a);
    }
}
```

The alternative is manually comparing a field, return the result if it's not zero, otherwise move onto the next field and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also a beginner for java, so please forgive me if my explanation is in question. The interface `Comparable` is use for sorting, so firstly you must tell us what do you want to sort by. For example, you can sort your locations by elevation by this:

```
public int compareTo(Location a){ //must compare objs and return an int
    if(elevation < a.getElevation()){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(elevation == a.getElevation()){
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Hope my answer helpful and wish you successful.